# How to rewrite code of google geo chart to use it with angular (angular-google-charts)?

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization

I started playing around with google-charts in a simple html-file and I actually really got the result I was looking for. For this I used alot of "google. ...." methods. Now I want to use this code in my Angular-Application (with angular-google-charts) and for that I kind of have to convert my code.

My html-file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .google-visualization-tooltip { 
        width: 150px !important;
        background-color: #515152 !important;
        position: absolute !important;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
    <!--================================================================================================-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages':['geochart'],
        'mapsApiKey': 'myKey'
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Country');
        dataTable.addColumn('number', 'amount');
        dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'})

        dataTable.addRows([
          ['Country', 0, ''],
          ['India', 2, 'visited'],
          ['Australia', 4, 'want to visit'],
          ['Germany', 1, 'homecountry'],
          ['United States', 2,  'visited'],
          ['Brazil', 2, 'visited'],
          ['Canada', 3, 'favorite destination'],
          ['France', 2, 'visited'],
          ['Russia', 2, 'visited']
        ]);

    var options = {
      backgroundColor: '#17263c',
      datalessRegionColor: '#242f3e',
      /*legend: {
        textStyle: {
          color: 'blue',
          fontSize: '16'
        }
      },*/
      legend: 'none',
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true,
        textStyle: {
          color: 'white'
        }
      },
      colors: ['#46127A', '#1102BB', '#1633C4', '#3185CE']
    };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

      chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }
    </script>
    <!--================================================================================================-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="regions_div" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is what I already have:

```
<google-chart #chart
   [title]="title"
   [type]="type"
   [data]="data"
   [columnNames]="columnNames"
   [options]="options"
   [firstRowIsData]="false"
   style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</google-chart>
```

```
type="GeoChart";
  data = [
    ['Country', 'amount', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}],
    ['Country', 0, ''],
    ['India', 2, 'visited'],
    ['Australia', 4, 'want to visit'],
    ['Germany', 1, 'homecountry'],
    ['United States', 2,  'visited'],
    ['Brazil', 2, 'visited'],
    ['Canada', 3, 'favorite destination'],
    ['France', 2, 'visited'],
    ['Russia', 2, 'visited']      
  ];
  options = {
    backgroundColor: '#17263c',
    datalessRegionColor: '#242f3e',
    legend: 'none',
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true,
      textStyle: {
        color: 'black'
      }
    },
    colors: ['#46127A', '#1102BB', '#1633C4', '#3185CE']
  };
```

Now what I don't know is how to define a 3. column for the chart where I can set the tooltip and I don't know how to add the CSS. Because there is a lot of this google. ... I thought I have to import { google } from ' I don't know where' and I wouldn't really know how to use it then.

I would be really happy, if someone could give me an example that
1. allows me to create chart-data with 3 columns (same as in the first code snippet) and that
2. allows me to use the CSS ( .google-visualization-tooltip { })

Edit: I added something to get a 3. column in the code above that now gives me this error:

```
core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Unknown type of value in 0,2
    at gvjs_Rba (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:130)
    at Object.gvjs_Eo [as arrayToDataTable] (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:130)
    at GoogleChartComponent.updateChart (angular-google-charts.js:266)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (angular-google-charts.js:473)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at angular-google-charts.js:89
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the column headings as part of the data...

```
data = [
  ['Country', 'amount', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}],
  ['Country', 0, ''],
  ['India', 2, 'visited'],
  ['Australia', 4, 'want to visit'],
  ['Germany', 1, 'homecountry'],
  ['United States', 2,  'visited'],
  ['Brazil', 2, 'visited'],
  ['Canada', 3, 'favorite destination'],
  ['France', 2, 'visited'],
  ['Russia', 2, 'visited']      
];
```

when passing column headings, there is a property (`firstRowIsData`) that must be false.
false is the default, so if you have set it to true somewhere, just remove it...

```
<raw-chart [firstRowIsData]="true"></raw-chart>
```

as for css, you can include in your html as normal...

Comment: okay I changed it but now I get the following error: ```core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Unknown type of value in 0,2
    at gvjs_Rba (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:130)
    at Object.gvjs_Eo [as arrayToDataTable] (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:130)
    at GoogleChartComponent.updateChart (angular-google-charts.js:266)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (angular-google-charts.js:473)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
 ```

Comment: and you're sure `firstRowIsData` is false?

Comment: yes I added it to be sure and I edited the code in the question, have a look to be sure.

Comment: ok, if you remove the third column from each row, and leave the column headings (for the first two columns) , does it work then? -- I don't use angular, so don't have a good way to test, have you ever used [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)? can you put an example there?

Comment: it partly works then: at least a map is shown but the colors don't work and If I hover over a country only the number but not the countryname is shown. I will try to set up an example on stackblitz, never did that before.

Comment: My main problem is that I actually don't know how to import the package I need. In ANgular Cli it would be: npm install angular-google-charts but in Stackblitz I don't know how to get it

Comment: Okay I'm sorry, I am not able to set up a project on Stackblitz...

Comment: If you want I could send you the project but for that you would have to setup an environment which isn't that complicated

Answer (score 0):

I now found a way:
I didn't use the angular-google-charts libary. For this I added the script in intex.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

In the component.html I basically wrote this:

```
<div id="regions_div" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

And in component.ts I used the ngOnInit-Method for this:

```
ngOnInit() {

google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages':['geochart'],
  'mapsApiKey': 'myKey'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Country');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'amount');
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'})

  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Country', 0, ''],
    ['India', 2, 'visited'],
    ['Australia', 4, 'want to visit'],
    ['Germany', 1, 'homecountry'],
    ['United States', 2,  'visited'],
    ['Brazil', 2, 'visited'],
    ['Canada', 3, 'favorite destination'],
    ['France', 2, 'visited'],
    ['Russia', 2, 'visited']
  ]);

var options = {
backgroundColor: '#17263c',
datalessRegionColor: '#242f3e',
legend: 'none',
tooltip: {
  isHtml: true,
  textStyle: {
    color: 'black'
  }
},
colors: ['#46127A', '#1102BB', '#1633C4', '#3185CE']
};

var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

Now there is an error that appears while compiling:

```
 ERROR in src/app/components/chart/chart.component.ts(65,27): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ backgroundColor: string; datalessRegionColor: string; legend: string; tooltip: { isHtml: boolean; textStyle: { color: string; }; }; colors: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GeoChartOptions'.
  Types of property 'legend' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"none" | ChartLegend'.
```

But this basically just tells me that my options aren't correct but in the view on the page everything is displayed correctly anyway.